# Android JPA JSON custom child object reading problems

Tags: java, android, json, jpa

I have the JSON Array below, created by a JPA function on a WebService:

```
[{"Producao":{"cliente":{"id":3,"nome_fantasia":"animal"},"data":"2013-11-08T00:00:00-02:00","id":1,"liberado":0,"prazo":"2013-11-14T00:00:00-02:00","produto":{"codigo_desenho":"CODIGO","dependencia":0,"descricao":"Produto1","disponivel":1,"id":39,"qtde":1,"raiz":0},"qtde":1}},{"Producao":{"cliente":{"id":1,"nome_fantasia":"bem"},"data":"2013-11-08T00:00:00-02:00","id":2,"liberado":0,"prazo":"2013-11-14T00:00:00-02:00","produto":{"codigo_desenho":"","dependencia":0,"descricao":"teste3","disponivel":1,"id":35,"qtde":1,"raiz":0},"qtde":2}}]
```

And I have to read it in my Android App. Converting them to a List.
The Object "Producao" has the Object "Cliente" as attribute.

I'm trying to do as below:

```
public static Producao jSONToProducao(JSONObject json) throws JSONException, ParseException{
        JSONObject jPro = json.getJSONObject("Producao");
        Producao producao = new Producao();
        producao.setId(jPro.getInt("id"));
    producao.setCliente(ClienteDAO.jSONToCliente(jPro.getJSONObject("cliente")));
    .
    .
    .
    return producao;
}
```

Where ClienteDAO.jSONToClient is:

```
public static Cliente jSONToCliente(JSONObject json) throws JSONException{
        JSONObject jCli = json.getJSONObject("Cliente");
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.setId(jCli.getInt("id"));
        cliente.setNome_fantasia(jCli.getString("nome_fantasia"));
    return cliente;
}
```

but the line `producao.setCliente(ClienteDAO.jSONToCliente(jPro.getJSONObject("cliente")))` returns:

> JSON Exception ~> No value for cliente”. ¬¬'

I tried to read it as a JSONArray too, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JSON Exception ~> No value for cliente

because you are passing `cliente` JSONObject to `jSONToCliente` method from `jSONToProducao` so change your code as to get all values from `cliente` JSONObject :

```
public static Cliente jSONToCliente(JSONObject json) throws JSONException{
     // json contain only cliente JSONObject
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.setId(json.getInt("id"));
        cliente.setNome_fantasia(json.getString("nome_fantasia"));
    return cliente;
}
```